# I can't use OneHotEncoder for days

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I want to use OneHotEncoder for days. The column name is day and includes Sun, Sat, Thur, Fri

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Thur'

```py
import pandas as pd

veriler = pd.read_csv("tips.csv")

days=veriler.iloc[:,4:5].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features="all")
days=ohe.fit_transform(days).toarray()
```

```sh
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Thur'
```

Comment: Could you provide an extract of **tips.csv**

Comment: One waiter recorded information about each tip he received over a period of a few months working in one restaurant. In all he recorded 244 tips.

I want to predict the tips amount for each guest using the column tip as the target. The columns name are total_bill, tip, sex, smoker(yes or no), day, time(dinner or lunch) and size

Comment: (1) Please translate the comments or remove them (2) Please show what is printed or remove the print statements. (3) Please split `ohe.fit_transform(days).toarray()` into two lines. Which one fails? (4) Remove the unnecessary imports - you might also want to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)